# После запуска кода и успешного ввода пароля, openAI отвечает один раз и на остальные вопросы/задачи не реагирует

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
import telebot
import openai
import logging
from telebot.types import Message
bot = telebot.TeleBot('666')
openai.api_key = 'sk-666'

conversations = {}
# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(filename='bot.log', level=logging.ERROR)


def openai_chat(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    if chat_id not in conversations:
        conversations[chat_id] = []

    conversation = conversations[chat_id]

    # Если это первое сообщение в разговоре, добавляем его в конец списка сообщений
    if len(conversation) == 0:
        conversation.append({'role': 'user', 'content': message.text})
    else:
        # Обновляем ожидающее ответа сообщение ассистента
        conversation[-1]['content'] = message.text

    try:
        # Вызываем OpenAI API для получения ответа
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=conversation,
            temperature=0.1,
            max_tokens=1050,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
        )

        # Добавляем ответ ассистента в разговор
        conversation.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': response.choices[0].message.content})

        # Отправляем ответ ассистента пользователю
        bot.reply_to(message, response.choices[0].message.content)

    except Exception as e:
        # Логируем любые ошибки, возникающие во время вызова API
        logging.error(str(e))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('OpenAI')

    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите вариант: \n1: OpenAI - Чат-ассистент', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def authorization(message):
    if message.text == 'OpenAI':
        markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль для входа', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, login)


def login(message):
    if message.chat.id not in conversations:
        conversations[message.chat.id] = []

    if message.text == 'PASSWRD':
        sent2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вход выполнен. Теперь вы можете начать диалог с виртуальным ассистентом')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent2, openai_chat)
    else:
        markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        sent3 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный пароль. Повторите ввод пароля', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent3, login)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

OpenAI после успешного вводя пароля отвечает, но отвечает один раз на одно сообщение, что исправить в коде что-бы диалог не прерывался на этом.